# Configuring MSDeploy 3.5 WS2008 R2

Tags: msdeploy

I try to configure msdeploy configuration between two WS2008 R2 servers.
I don't have any domain controller

I Installed MSDeploy 3.5 using Web PI on both servers.

I created a user on both servers, and added them to the "Administrators" group
I use this user for syncrhonization :

```
SET USERNAME=WebDeploy
SET PASSWORD=blah
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy" -verb:sync -source:webServer -dest:auto,computername=x.x.x;X,username=%USERNAME%,password=%PASSWORD% -skip:objectName=contentPath,absolutePath="\\temp"
```

I get ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN error.

I went to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN

I created the group, added my user to it, stil the samme error.

I saw that MSDeploy created users WDeployAdmin and WDeployConfigWriter, I also tried with those.

I launch my synchronization script with elevated privileges.

Any clue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding the following registry key : https://serverfault.com/questions/38999/cant-connect-to-default-admin-share-on-windows-2008

It solved my administrative share problem as well as my WSDeploy problem.